Undefined Reference WinMain@16 in Makefile
I have a makefile here to build a graphics engine altho i keep getting this one undefined reference which i can't seem to figure out.
Take a look and tell me what you think.
I have a main function in main.c and i have countless folders with source files in them all being compiled together and i don't know what is wrong.
Makefile:
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Iinclude
LDFLAGS=-Llib -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lgdi32 -lmingw32 -mwindows
SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=gengine.exe

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    del $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "engine/global.h"

static bool should_quit = false;
static vec2 pos;

static void input_handle(void) {
    if (global.input.escape == KS_PRESSED || global.input.escape == KS_HELD)
                should_quit = true;

    i32 x, y;
    SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
    pos[0] = (f32)x;
    pos[1] = global.render.height - y;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    time_init(60);
    config_init();
    render_init(800, 600, "OpenGL Engine - C : Gengine");
    physics_init();

    pos[0] = global.render.width * 0.5;
    pos[1] = global.render.height * 0.5;

    SDL_ShowCursor(false);

    AABB test_aabb = {
        .position = {global.render.width * 0.5, global.render.height * 0.5},
        .half_size = {50, 50}
    };

    AABB cursor_aabb = {.half_size = {75, 75}};

    AABB sum_aabb = {
        .position = {test_aabb.position[0], test_aabb.position[1]},
        .half_size = {
            test_aabb.half_size[0] + cursor_aabb.half_size[0],
            test_aabb.half_size[1] + cursor_aabb.half_size[1]}
    };

    while (!should_quit) {
        time_update();

        SDL_Event event;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
                    switch (event.type) {
                    case SDL_QUIT:
                            should_quit = true;
                            break;
                    default:
                            break;
                    }
            }

        input_update();
        input_handle();
        physics_update();

        render_begin();

        cursor_aabb.position[0] = pos[0];
        cursor_aabb.position[1] = pos[1];

        render_aabb((f32*)&test_aabb, WHITE);

            render_aabb((f32*)&sum_aabb, (vec4){1, 1, 1, 0.5});

        render_aabb((f32*)&cursor_aabb, WHITE);

        AABB minkowski_difference = aabb_minkowski_difference(test_aabb, cursor_aabb);
        render_aabb((f32*)&minkowski_difference, ORANGE);

        if (physics_point_intersect_aabb(pos, test_aabb))
            render_quad(pos, (vec2){10, 10}, RED);
        else
            render_quad(pos, (vec2){10, 10}, WHITE);

        render_end();
        time_update_late();
    }

    return 0;
}


I tried saving files and adding windows headers and macros but nothing made the undefined reference go away.
Error is:
gcc -o gengine.exe src/engine/global.o -Llib -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lgdi32 -mwindows
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'gengine.exe' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gengine.exe] Error 1

C:\Users\Ralph\Dev\C-C++\Gengine>


The graphics engine may require you to use WinMain() instead of main().

That didn't work either already tried it.

Please post the error message.

C:\Users\Ralph\Dev\C-C++\Gengine>mingw32-make
gcc -o gengine.exe src/engine/global.o -Llib -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lgdi32 -lmingw32 -mwindows
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'gengine.exe' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gengine.exe] Error 1
C:\Users\Ralph\Dev\C-C++\Gengine>

Please edit your question and put the error message into the question itself, with proper formatting as a code block, rather than in a comment where it can't be formatted to be readable.  Have you tried running sdl2-config --cflags --libs to see what options you should be providing?

sdl2-config is no such thing in windows i dont think

I think -Llib needs to be -LC:\path\to\SDL2\lib. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896513/setting-up-sdl2-with-mingw-and-sublime-text

sdl libraries are alr located in lib folder in my project

@RemyLebeau The duplicate link is wrong. MinGW supports both main and WinMain always, regardless of compiler settings.

The error is caused by not linking SDL2main, as explained here. Since you did try to link it, this means the version of SDL2 you used is incompatible with your compiler (x32 vs x64 bits). Since your compiler is also quite outdated (GCC 6, while the latest is 14), I recommend uninstalling it and replacing it with MSYS2, and installing SDL2 using it as well (you get the latest GCC, and a version of SDL2 that's guaranteed to be compatible with it).

@Barmar Both work. If it didn't work, the linker would complain about not being able to find the library...
