# SDL2 Windows undefined reference to `WinMain@16' with Eclipse

Tags: c++

I have this snippet of code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error reported is this:

> Info: Internal Builder is used for build g++ -o
> cavestory-developement.exe "src\cavestory-developement.o" -lmingw32
> -lSDL2main -lSDL2  c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0):
> undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
> exit status
>
> 17:13:45 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 205ms)

Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048072/sdl-2-undefined-reference-to-winmain16-and-several-sdl-functions

Comment: o thank you andy, i tried #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED, and it seems to have worked. I tried before but i didn't save before building.